# What subtyping/supertyping rule in the Java Language Specification allows this assignment?

Tags: java, jls

Suppose I have this (contrived) situation:

```
public final Comparable<? super Number> frob() {
  return x -> 0; // whatever
}

final Comparable<? super Integer> c = frob();
```

The JLS defines [assignability of reference types in terms of supertypes and subtypes only](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.2).  Fine.

One of the [direct supertypes of a parameterized type is an otherwise equivalent parameterized type with an appropriate *containing* type (a wildcard expression) in one of its type argument slots](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2).  A parameterized type with the same raw type and owner type and that [containing type argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) (among its others) is thus a direct supertype of the original parameterized type.  (So by these rules `Comparable<?>` is a *direct supertype* of `Comparable<Whatever>`, as is `Comparable<? extends Whatever>`, and `Comparable<? super Whatever>`, and plenty of others that section 4.5.1 lays out.)

The implication of all this is, loosely speaking, if you have a "receiver" reference `a` bearing type `A` in your left hand, and a "payload" reference `b` bearing type `B` in your right hand, then `b` is assignable to `a` if and only if `A` is a supertype (not just direct) of `B`.  So presumably what the compiler does is calculate `B`'s supertypes, and then see if the resulting collection of types contains `A`.

I must be wrong in this presumption, though, because analyzing the supertypes of `Comparable<? super Number>` by itself following these rules will seemingly never yield `Comparable<? super Integer>`.  (That is, looking at just the type arguments, if you "start from" `Number` and "go up" its supertype hierarchy to calculate its containing types, you'll never "reach" `Integer`, because as we all know `Integer` is a *subtype* of `Number`, not a supertype of it.)

So in my example above, **what rules in the JLS permit `Comparable<? super Integer>` to be derived as a direct supertype of `Comparable<? super Number>`**?  Is it to be found in the [section on type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2.3), even though to my eye there's no inference going on here (i.e. no diamond operator, no `var`, etc.)?

To make it clear: my problem is not with the assignment, which I know in practice is of course just fine (if the example method above returns a new `Comparable<Object>` anonymous class, for example, that would work).  It's with my understanding of how the JLS allows this.

Comment: "Contains" doesn't mean supertype. Per the rules in [4.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1-400), `? super T <= ? super S` if `S <: T`. So if `Integer <: Number`, `? super Integer` _contains_ `? super Number`.

Comment: I don’t say it does.

Comment: A parameterized type `P<A>` does have as one of its direct supertypes another parameterized type whose type argument is a containing type of `A`—that's pretty explicit, so as noted in my example `P<? extends A>` is a supertype of `P<A>` according to the rules, even though `? extends A` is not a supertype, direct or otherwise, of `A`.

Comment: (Sorry; mistyped `extends` for `super` in my comment above, though it still basically holds: supertypes are reflexive so `P<? extends A>` and `P<? super A>` are both among the direct supertypes of `P<A>` per section 4.5.1.)